# Enumerate array placed in torch.autograd.Variable

Tags: python, pytorch

I have variable `xy` that loads data from file and is used to create `x_data` and `y_data` variables of type `torch.autograd.Variable` . I suppose  `x_data` and `y_data` content are arrays. But how to enumerate that array in order to print content?

```
d = r"C:\gdrive\python\diabetes.csv"
import torch
from torch.autograd import Variable 
import numpy as np
import torch.nn.functional as F
xy = np.loadtxt(d,delimiter=',',dtype=np.float32 )
print("***")
print(xy)
x_data = Variable(torch.from_numpy(xy[:,0:-1]))
y_data=  Variable(torch.from_numpy(xy[:,[-1]]))
```

Comment: Which pytorch version are you using? After 1.0, torch.Tensor and torch.autograd.Variable are the same class. So you can iterate as you would a tensor. [Migration guide](https://pytorch.org/blog/pytorch-0_4_0-migration-guide/)

Answer (score 0):

You can enumerate/iterate over Pytorch tensors the same way you can for numpy arrays and standard Python objects.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to iterate pytorch tensors just like python lists:

```
import torch
from torch.autograd import Variable
import numpy as np
import torch.nn.functional as F

d = r"C:\gdrive\python\diabetes.csv"
xy = np.loadtxt(d, delimiter=',', dtype=np.float32)
print("***")
x_data = Variable(torch.from_numpy(xy[:,0:-1]))
y_data = Variable(torch.from_numpy(xy[:,[-1]]))

print(x_data.shape)
print(y_data.shape)
for i, (x, y) in enumerate(zip(x_data, y_data)):
    print("example:", i)
    print("features:", x)
    print("label:", y)
    print()
```